# Why ImageButton and Button have different heights for the same size?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button, imagebutton

The problem is the following.
I have an ImageButton and a Button, they have the same height and width. But the ImageButton is stretched to cover the entire area, but the Button is not. I need the Button to also fill the area completely in height.

Screenshots and code:

[ImageButton and Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtSLl.png)

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backspaceImageBtn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_backspace_image_btn"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/light_btn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/numbers_8Btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/numbers_8Btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/numbers_8Btn"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_backspace" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/symbol_divideBtn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="@string/symbol_divide"
        android:textColor="@color/light_text"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/light_btn"
        app:cornerRadius="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/numbers_9Btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/numbers_9Btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/numbers_9Btn" />
```

I am a beginner, so I will be grateful in solving my little problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button`s have some built-in margins that you can't easily get rid of. But you can make any `View` clickable, such as a `TextView` or an `ImageView`. And these classes don't have the built-in margin to worry about. So don't restrict yourself to just `Button`s when you want something that's clickable.